# Use of AJAX in content page when AJAX is already used in master page

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an asp.net web application. I have used master page.In master page I have used a web user control as the right menu . The right menu uses the AJAX accordion. When I try to use AJAX in my content page, it does not allow to use it.

```
Error pops up: No script Manager found.
```

When I add script manager, there pops up an

```
error , more than 1 instance of script manager found.
```

how to add `ajax` in content page in such situation?